# Plo files missing while building Xerces-C

Tags: linux, xerces, xerces-c

I am trying to build xerces-c on a RedHat Linux system. I am able to execute ./configure successfully but on running the **make** command I am getting the following errors

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/fbnbkadm/xerces-c-3.1.4'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/fbnbkadm/xerces-c-3.1.4/src'
Makefile:3659: .deps/stricmp.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3660: .deps/strnicmp.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3661: .deps/towlower.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3662: .deps/towupper.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3663: .deps/root_res.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3664: .deps/xercesc_messages.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3665: xercesc/dom/.deps/DOMException.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3666: xercesc/dom/.deps/DOMLSException.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3667: xercesc/dom/.deps/DOMRangeException.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3668: xercesc/dom/.deps/DOMXPathException.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3669: xercesc/dom/impl/.deps/DOMAttrImpl.Plo: No such file or directory
.
.
.
Makefile:3974: xercesc/validators/schema/identity/.deps/XPathSymbols.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3975: xercesc/validators/schema/identity/.deps/XercesXPath.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3976: xercesc/xinclude/.deps/XIncludeDOMDocumentProcessor.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3977: xercesc/xinclude/.deps/XIncludeLocation.Plo: No such file or directory
Makefile:3978: xercesc/xinclude/.deps/XIncludeUtils.Plo: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `xercesc/xinclude/.deps/XIncludeUtils.Plo'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/fbnbkadm/xerces-c-3.1.4/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/fbnbkadm/xerces-c-3.1.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am not exactly sure if I am following the correct process. Kindly help

Comment: Suggest : Download a new package, xerces-c-3.1.4.tar.xz . ... E.g. https://archive.apache.org/dist/xerces/c/3/sources/xerces-c-3.1.4.tar.xz ... is OK . Please make sure the "BuildRequires" are installed : `fdupes gcc-c++ libicu-devel pkgconfig`

Comment: @KnudLarsen The package is already downloaded. if I run the command it says "fdupes: command not found"

Comment: fdupes: Probable used for building xerses-c rpm packages. ... Install "build prerequisites" for xerses-c : `yum install fdupes gcc-c++ libicu-devel pkgconfig` .... Packages download:  `xerces-c-3.1.4-5.1.x86_64.rpm` ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home%3A/chaudhari%3A/experiments/RHEL_7/x86_64/xerces-c-3.1.4-5.1.x86_64.rpm .... `libxerces-c-devel-3.1.4-5.1.x86_64.rpm` ftp://ftp.pbone.net/mirror/ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/opensuse/repositories/home:/chaudhari:/experiments/RHEL_7/x86_64/libxerces-c-devel-3.1.4-5.1.x86_64.rpm